# Как выбрать template?

Tags: spring, java

STS Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE

Выбираю `File->New->Spring Project`

Ввожу имя проекта. Далее нужно указать template. Но его нет:

[image]

Нажимаю на `Configure templates`...

[image]

Но вроде они есть. Как выбрать template?